# display format string for DBNull not working as expected

Tags: c#, displayformat

Hi all I have applied display format string for a label as follows

```
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Price")!=DBNull.Value? string.Format("{0:c}", Eval("Price")) :string.Format("{0:c}","0.00") %>' />
```

This is displaying the amount with `$` symbol when it is having data but when null for `0.00` it is not displaying the `$` symbol can some one help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass some numeric literal into `Format` method, so that the currency format `{0:c}` can be applied, but you are passing string literal `"0.00"`. Try to change `"0.00"` literal to either `0.0` or `0` or `0.00`, choose the most readable literal for you.

write

```
string.Format("{0:c}", 0.00) //returns $0.00. 
//The same result for any numeric zero literal
```

instead of

```
string.Format("{0:c}", "0.00") //returns 0.00
```

You can also simplify code a bit to:

```
<%# string.Format("{0:c}", Eval("Price") != DBNull.Value ? Eval("Price") : 0 ) %>
```